# Vue: Import router in helper class and push route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, vue-router

I'm using `Vue` for the first time and try to `import` my current `router` instance to a `JavaScript` `class`, where I handle the `Authentification`.

So this is my `router` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import FirstRoute from '@/components/FirstRoute';
import SecondRoute from '@/components/SecondRoute';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      meta: { requiredAuth: false },
      name: 'FirstRoute',
      component: FirstRoute,
    },
    {
      path: '/second',
      meta: { requiredAuth: false },
      name: 'SecondRoute',
      component: SecondRoute,
    },
  ],
});
```

This is my helper `class` file, where I try to import and reuse the existing `router` instance, to `push` a `route` in a `function`:

```
import Router from '../router'; /* This is where I import the router instance */

const globalRouter = new Router(); /* Attempt 1 */

class AuthService {
  constructor() {
    console.log(Router); /* This console.log() shows me my router instance with all routes - so it was imported the right way and works */
    const routerInClass = new Router(); /* Attempt 2 */

    this.doSomething();
  }
}

doSomething() {
  const routerInFunction = new Router(); /* Attempt 3 */

  /* Results of my attempts: */
  console.log(globalRouter); /* Result Attempt 1: undefined */
  console.log(routerInClass); /* Result Attempt 2: undefined */
  console.log(routerInFunction); /* Result Attempt 3: undefined */
  console.log(Router); /* Result Attempt 4: undefined */

  /* Use imported router to push a route */
  Router.push({ path: '/SecondRoute' }); /* Not working with attempt 1 to 4 */
}
```

**Use case behind it:** I check, if the `auth token` has expired. If true, I save my current `href` using `window.location.href` in the `localStorage` and when logging in again, I redirect to the previous page. Now I'm trying to use the `Router`, because the redirect flickers and I hope it will be smoother with the `Router.

This are my attempts, which all failed. I can log the `Router` in the `constructor`, but in my `function` it is always `undefined`. I can't do the `push` there. Any ideas?

Comment: the function is outside the class, so it has no access to the class. Maybe thats whats going wrong.

Comment: @NielsLucas I managed to fix it by myself: Actually, my `Attempt 1` was the right way, but I don't have to create a `new Router()` I can just assign the imported one to a variable like this: `const globalRouter = Router;` and in my function I can do this: `globalRouter.push({ path: '/sample' });`. This works fine for me.

Comment: Why would you assign Router in another variable tho. Why dont you just use Router.push() direct?

Comment: @NielsLucas If so, than `Router` is undefined. If reassigning it into a variable it works. I have really no idea why....and the code above shows how my file is structured, so nothing else, which could cause some black magic..

Comment: This may sound weird. But I has some scenario that some import {SomeValue} was undefined when i console.log it, but when I tried using the function on it: SomeValue.someFunction(), everything was ok. Is this maybe the case for you as well?

Let me know.

Comment: Ow nevermind, in you example you already tried that.

Comment: @NielsLucas Yes, I tried it with `Router.push()`. Don't really know why, it's also confusing myself as well...

Answer (score 2):

In your helper file, you don't need to import Vue nor VueRouter

```
import router from '../router';

class AuthService {
    constructor() {
        console.log(router);
        this.doSomething();
    }

    doSomething() {
        /* Use imported router to push a route */
        router.push({ path: '/SecondRoute' });
    }
}
```

EDIT : move the doSomething function in your class

Comment: Alright, removing the `import` for `Vue` and `VueRouter` makes sense. But this doesn't change the fact, that the `import` of `router` stays the same as I do and also the `router.push` does not work, because the imported `router` is `undefined` in my function `doSomething()`. So you just refactored a little bit the code, but the logic is the same and not working. This should not be an answer, maybe a comment or bether an edit of my question. Read the question carefully. Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: you're right, I've could add a comment but I can't because I don't have enough reputation. BTW, I edited the code to move the function doSomething in the class

Comment: I managed to fix it by myself: Actually, my `Attempt 1` was the right way, but I don't have to create a `new Router()` I can just assign the imported one to a variable like this: const globalRouter = Router; and in my function I can do this: `const globalRouter.push({ path: '/sample' });`. This works fine for me.

Comment: you even don't need to affect it in a var, you can use Router directly because it is the object you have export in your router.js file, as to know, your new Router object. You should rename it in lowercase to avoid misunderstanding or directly `import globalRouter from '../router'`

Comment: This does not work for me, if the `doSomething()` function is not within the `class`.